# Mean of RasterLayer will Not Compute (R Raster Package)

Tags: r, mean, raster, r-raster

So, I have stacked multiple rasters (x1, x2, x3, x4, ...) and successfully computed a mean raster from all of those (xmaster). However, I then want the mean pixel value of that raster (xmaster). Normally I would display the summary statistics and call the mean value.... however no mean appears in the summary for 'xmaster'! I am not sure why- I am wondering if someone would kindly help me with a work around. Please see my below script:

```
lightstackFF<-list.files()
stacklights<-stack(lightstackFF)
xmaster<- mean(stacklights, na.rm=TRUE)
summary(xmaster)
```

"> summary(xmaster)
        layer
Min.    11488
1st Qu. 18016
Median  20048
3rd Qu. 21968
Max.    28704
NA's        0"

As you guys can see, no mean value appears for the raster. Of course I can save the raster out and extract the mean in another software- but its very time consuming. Can anyone help me out as to why this is not showing the mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
summary(xmaster[])    # Please note the []
# which is equivalent to:
summary(values(xmaster))
# or even
summary(getValues(xmaster))
```

This applies `summary` to a *vector containing all the values* of your `RasterLayer` (and not to the `RasterLayer` *itself*). This should give you the following info (hence including the mean):

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
```

Comment: Thanks ztl! Not sure why it wouldn;t display the mean with just the summary- but this works and I will be sure to use it for now on!

Answer (score 2):

Summary functions (min, max, mean, etc.) in the [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package return a new raster object where each cell is a new computed value. `raster::cellStats()` is needed to return a single summary of all cell values in a layer.  For example, to obtain the mean of layer means, you could use something like the following:

```
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
rs <- stack(r,r,r)
layermeans <- cellStats(rs, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
u <- mean(layermeans)
> layermeans
 layer.1  layer.2  layer.3 
5.028814 5.028814 5.028814 
> u
[1] 5.028814
```